# How to override server time in config.php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to know how to override server time ,
my server is in UK but my Client is in Singapore and he wants Singapore time.
in php.ini date.timezone is Europe/London which i do not want to change. i want to handle from config.php
i tried this in codeigniter config.php

```
$config['time_diff']= "+8";
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

i also even tried this

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
date_default_timezone_set('Singapore');
```

Comment: $config['default_site_timezone'] = 'yourtimezone';

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within **config.php**

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
```

Comment: It works thanks
I do not know is it codeigniter fault or mine but putting this code date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
at top of config.php works fine but if i put this code in mid or bottom of codeigniter config.php then it do not work

Comment: That's why I've shown the above code to place it where it'll work as charm. Glad to help. (**FYI:** _If this answer helps you then you can accept it or vote up too_)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use codeigniter date helper functions.

Go to application/config.php and set time_reference from local to your timezone.

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'Europe/London';
```

Now load date helper inside your controller

```
$this->load->helper('date');

echo now(); // it returns UNIX timestamp according to timezone set in config.
```

you can also pass timezone as parameter in now() function.

```
echo now('America/Los_Angeles');
```

References - 
system/helpers/date_helper.php 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html